# Twitter API similar to Google Alert

Tags: php, web-applications, twitter, google-alerts

I am trying to create a web application which have a similar functionality with Google Alerts. (by similar I mean, the user can provide their email address for the alert to be sent to, daily or hourly) The only limitation is that it only gives alerts to user based on a certain keyword or hashtag. I think that I have found the fundamental API needed for this web application.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

The problem is I still don't know all the web technologies needed for this application to work properly. For example, Do I have to store all of the searched keywords in database? Do I have to keep pooling ajax request all the time in order to keep my database updated? What if the keyword the user provided is very popular right now that might have thousands of tweets just in an hour (not to mention, there might be several emails that request several trending topics)?

By the way, I am trying to build this application using PHP. So please let me know, what kind of techniques I need to learn for such web app (and some references maybe)? Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Regards,

Felix Perdana

Comment: Look for the comet techology.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the advice..any other idea?

Comment: I was wrong. You don't need comet technology, look at the answer. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should store user's e-mails and search keywords (or whatever) in the database.

Then your app should make API queries (so it should be run by a server) to get some relevant data. Then you have to send data to the all users.

To understand here is the algorithm:

1. User adds his request to the page like http://www.google.ru/alerts
2. You store his e-mail and keyword in the database.
3. Then your server runs script (you can loop it or use cron) which makes queries to the Twitter to get some data.
4. Your script process all the data and send it to the user's e-mails.